# Chart.js how to show and hide charts with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, bar-chart

So i have 2 bar charts displayed: 2 Charts

[image: 1]

The first bar chart id="myChart" (January to November) is the chart where it can be altered by the Date Range Filter button and Reset button.

The second bar chart id="myChart2" (September to November) is the chart that cant be altered by the Date Range Filter button and Reset button. Basically it is only for display.

What I wanted to do is that the default page display should be the second bar chart and when the user clicks on the Filter button, the second bar chart will be replaced by the first bar chart. And when the user clicks on the Reset button, it will now go back to displaying the second bar chart.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 form-inline button-container">
                  <!-- DATE RANGE FILTER AND RESET -->
                  <label class="mr-sm-2">Start Date: </label>
                  <input id = "start" type= "date" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"> 
                  <label class="mr-sm-2">End Date: </label>
                  <input id = "end" type = "date" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"> 

                  <button class = "btn btn-success mb-2 mr-2" name = "search" onclick = "filterDate()"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i> Filter </button> 
                  <button class = "btn btn-info mb-2 mr-2" onclick = "resetDate()"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrows-rotate"></i> Reset </button>
                  <button class = "btn btn-info mb-2 mr-2" onclick = "window.print();"><i class="fa-solid fa-print"></i> Print </button>
                </div>
                <div class="container chart-container">
                  <div class="sub-chart-container">
                    <!-- CHART -->
                    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and the SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // setup 

  // Date Array
  const dateArrayJS = <?php echo json_encode($dateArray); ?>

  const dateChartJS = dateArrayJS.map((day, index) => {
    let dayjs = new Date(day);
    return dayjs.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  });

  // Report Array
  const reportsArrayJS = <?php echo json_encode($reportsArray); ?>;

  const reportsChartJS = reportsArrayJS;
  console.log(new Date('2022-01-01 00:00:00 GMT+0800'));

  // Converted Dates for Filter
  const convertedDates = dateArrayJS.map(date => new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0));
  console.log(convertedDates);

  
  // data
  const data = {
    labels: dateChartJS,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Reports Recorded',
      data: reportsChartJS,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      skipNull: true
    }]
  };

  // config 
  const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Total number of reports received by month'
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'month'
          }
        },    
        y: {
          max: 20,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // setup 2

  // Date Array 2
  const dateArrayJS2 = <?php echo json_encode($dateArray2); ?>

  const dateChartJS2 = dateArrayJS2.map((day, index) => {
    let dayjs = new Date(day);
    return dayjs.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  });

  // Report Array 2
  const reportsArrayJS2 = <?php echo json_encode($reportsArray2); ?>;

  const reportsChartJS2 = reportsArrayJS2;
  console.log(new Date('2022-01-01 00:00:00 GMT+0800'));
  
  // data 2
  const data2 = {
    labels: dateChartJS2,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Reports Recorded',
      data: reportsChartJS2,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      skipNull: true
    }]
  };

  // config 2
  const config2 = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data2,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Total number of reports received by month'
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'month'
          }
        },    
        y: {
          max: 20,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // render chart
  const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'), config
  );

  // render chart 2
  const myChart2 = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart2'), config2
  );

  function filterDate(){
    const start1 = new Date(document.getElementById('start').value);
    const start = start1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    const end1 = new Date(document.getElementById('end').value);
    const end = end1.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    const filterDates = convertedDates.filter(date => date >= start && date <= end)
    myChart.config.data.labels = filterDates;
    
    const startArray = convertedDates.indexOf(filterDates[0])
    const endArray = convertedDates.indexOf(filterDates[filterDates.length - 1])
    console.log(endArray);
    
    const copyreportsChartJS = [...reportsChartJS];
    copyreportsChartJS.splice(endArray + 1, filterDates.length);
    copyreportsChartJS.splice(0, startArray);
    console.log(copyreportsChartJS);
    myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = copyreportsChartJS;
    
    myChart.update();
  }

  function resetDate(){
    myChart.config.data.labels = convertedDates;
    myChart.config.data.datasets[0].data = reportsChartJS;

    myChart.update();
  }

</script>
```

I did tried to searched on how to hide/show charts and encountered a youtube video about it but it uses checkboxes. But it is seems to be different from what i want.

Comment: This isn't really a charts thing. It's just a matter of showing and hiding _elements_ in general. I suggest expanding your search to that.

Comment: @isherwood will get on that thanks for the recommendation.